# Addition of two columns n display its result in third column of gridview

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

Rate AnodeRate TotalRate
100   100        200

txtrate,txtanoderate n txttatalrate are added in ItemTemplate of gridview.

rate field is in database table while anoderate n totalrate not in database table
,also totalrate is readonly so that user can see only its addition,this addition will b passed to txtrate field n wil get bind that value in database.
also i took
 `<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnTotalRt" runat="server" />` as it is readonly..

sample code:

```
enter code here
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Standard Rate">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtRate" runat="server" BorderWidth="0.5pt" Text='<%# Bind("rate") %>' BorderColor="green" BackColor="#ffffcc" Width="40px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtRate" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValAtSave" >*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ControlToValidate="txtRate" runat="server" ValidationExpression="[0-9]*.?[0-9]*" ValidationGroup="ValAtSave">
 Nos Pls.
 </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
          </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AnodeRate">
          <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtAnodeRate" runat="server" BorderWidth="0.5pt"
          BorderColor="green" BackColor="#ffffcc" Width="40px"></asp:TextBox>
          </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Rate" >
          <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalRate" runat="server" onchange="javascript:calculate_total_rate()" BorderWidth="0.5pt" Enabled="false"
          BorderColor="green" BackColor="#ffffcc" Width="40px"></asp:TextBox>
          </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

---

```
function calculate_total_rate()
{

document.getElementById('<%=txtTotalRate%>').value = ( document.getElementById('<%=txtRate.ClientID %>').value ) + (document.getElementById('<%=txtAnodeRate.ClientID %>').value );
document.getElementById('<%=hdnTotalRt.ClientID %>').value=  document.getElementById('<%=txtTotalRate.ClientID %>').value;

}
```

It is showing me error as The name "txtRate"does not exist in d current context

Answer (score 0):

> can you try with this code, (I have
>   replaced '=' in
>   document.getElementById('<%=txtTotalRate%>')
>   and
>   document.getElementById('<%=txtAnodeRate.ClientID
>   %>' by '#')

```
function calculate_total_rate()
{

document.getElementById('<%#txtTotalRate.ClientID%>').value = ( document.getElementById('<%=txtRate.ClientID %>').value ) + (document.getElementById('<%#txtAnodeRate.ClientID %>').value );
document.getElementById('<%=hdnTotalRt.ClientID %>').value=  document.getElementById('<%#txtTotalRate.ClientID %>').value;

}
```